# Creating a structure from bytes with ctypes and IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, ctypes

I have the following CPython code which I now try to run in IronPython:

```
import ctypes

class BarHeader(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("id", ctypes.c_char * 4),
        ("version", ctypes.c_uint32)]

bar_file = open("data.bar", "rb")
header_raw = bar_file.read(ctypes.sizeof(BarHeader))
header = BarHeader.from_buffer_copy(header_raw)
```

The last line raises this exception: `TypeError: expected array, got str`

I tried `BarHeader.from_buffer_copy(bytes(header_raw))` instead of the above, but then the exception message changes to `TypeError: expected array, got bytes`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the following code in Python 2.7 and it worked perfectly.

```
import ctypes  

class BarHeader(ctypes.Structure):
   _fields_ = [("version", ctypes.c_uint)]


header = BarHeader.from_buffer_copy("\x01\x00\x00\x00")
print header.version #prints 1 on little endian
```

And a solution using the array class

```
import ctypes
import array

class BarHeader(ctypes.Structure):
   _fields_ = [
      ("id", ctypes.c_char * 4),
      ("version", ctypes.c_uint32)]

bar_file = open("data.bar", "rb")

bytearray = array.array('b')
bytearray.fromfile(bar_file, ctypes.sizeof(BarHeader))

header = BarHeader.from_buffer_copy(bytearray)

print header.id
print header.version
```

Comment: But have you tried it in IronPython? Look at my question again :)

Comment: Have you tried it? Okay i am installing this now, only for you ;)

Comment: I don't understand why you posted the first sample, which doesn't work in IronPython. It's just like my original code, and like I stated, my code works in standard Python.

Your second sample works.

Comment: I didnt test it, so i posted it.
Ok tested second solution with "IronPython 2.6.1 for .NET 2.0 SP1" and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the struct module instead of ctypes for working with packed binary data.

It uses a format string, with characters defining the type of data to pack/unpack.

The documentation is found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html).
The format string to read an array of four chars, then a unsigned integer would be '4sI'.

's' is the character for char array, while 4 specifies length. 'I' is the character for unsigned int.

Example code:

```
import struct

header_fmt = struct.Struct("4sI")

bar_file = open("data.bar", "rb")
header_raw = bar_file.read(header_fmt.size)
id, version = header_fmt.unpack(header_raw)
```

Comment: Let me guess, you didn't test your answer in IronPython either. I know, because it doesn't work :)

But it can be fixed to work. However, my actual structures are a little bit more complex (I kept only 2 fields for this question), and I'd like to avoid working with "4sIIIIII16s16sQQQQ" strings

Comment: you can use number notation for any type. the example string could actually be expressed as "4s 6I 16s 16s 4Q"... and I forgot files couldn't be used as buffers. that code didn't work in stock python either ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, I was able to get this to work with IP version 2.7.5 using the Python 2.7 library.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")

import ctypes
import array

class BarHeader(ctypes.Structure):
   _fields_ = [("version", ctypes.c_uint)]

header = BarHeader.from_buffer_copy(array.array('c', ['\x01', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00']))
print header.version #prints 1 on little endian
```